# Covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The question is: 
Let $x_0$ be the common point of two circles in $X = S^1 \vee S^1$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the standard generators of $\pi_1(X, x_0) = \langle a, b\rangle$ corresponding
to the two $S^1$'s.

Draw a picture of the covering
space $p : (X, e xe0) → (X, x_0) $ so that the image $p∗(\pi_1(X, e xe0))$ is a subgroup
of $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ with generators $a^2, b^2$.

so I thought looking at the universal covering space, which is a 4-regular graph, and then identify all the points which identified by $a^2,b^2$ ... but I don't know how it is look like or even if it is true....

Comment: It may be somewhat easier in this type of problem to start with a point over $x_0$ and then draw paths (the paths correspond to $a$, $a^{-1}$, $b$, and $b^{-1}$).  If, in the covering space, the path should return to the starting point, return it to the starting point.  Otherwise, add a new point over $x_0$.

Comment: The covering space is the quotient space $\Gamma/\langle a^2, b^2 \rangle$, where $\Gamma$ is the Cayley graph of $\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$. As Michael Burr suggests, you should be able to draw this by tracing out paths, and returning back to the starting point according to your normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the covering space which is $X$ with a copy of the real line attached to each circle (not at the intersection point). At each integer point on the real lines, attach another copy of the real line. At each integer point on those real lines, attach another copy, and keep doing this (essentially creating something similar to the universal cover attached to each of the circles). I think $V$ is the cover you want.